# JAVA inheritance ( can't find out the difference )

Tags: java

I am doing tests to prepare for OCA and I got confused, while doing this task:

```
class A {
   private int i = 10;

   public void f() {}
   public void g() {}
}

class B extends A {
   public int i = 20;
   public void g() {}
}

public class C {
   A a = new A(); // 1
   A b = new B(); // 2
}
```

So I can't understand difference between `A a = new A();` and `A b = new B();`

I know.. this might be easy for you guys, but I cannot figure this out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A a = new A()` creates an object A and using this object you can access `f()` and `g()` methods in class A.

A b = new B() can be done because class B extends class A. The concept here is called `polymorphism`. Java allows user to assign a child object (B in this case) to parent reference (A in this case). Now using the object `b` you can access `f()` of class A as well. Note that it wouldn't have been possible if you had reference to class B (if you created `B b = new B()`).

Further, you can access `g()`, but since `g()` is present in class B, that takes precedence. So, `g()` of class B gets executed.

Try this example to understand more:

```
class A{
   private int i = 10;
   public void  f(){System.out.println(i);}
   public void g(){System.out.println(i+"**");}
}

class B extends A{
   public int i = 20;
   public void g(){System.out.println(i+"**********");}
}

public class C{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();//1
           A b = new B();//2
           a.f();
           b.f();
           b.g();
           a.g();

    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah... that's is what I needed.. makes much more sense, will play with code on eClipse..

Thanks mate !

Comment: One more question Sir., I understand how it works when I am calling methods. But... 

lets say I try to print `i`,   how to understand, without checking it on eClipse that for  example  `System.out.println(b.i)` or `System.out.println(a.i)`  wont work.

I know that I can make something like `B bb = new B();` and then call  `System.out.println(bb.i)` or use setters and getters,

But is there any simple rules to understand it ?      

Sorry.. missed link above, it makes more sense now..
Thanks for helping

Comment: Its almost similar. The variable corresponding to the object gets picked. If child variable is having its own variable, it gets precedence when called using child's object. Just check the values printed in the above program. you can play around by creating more variables and printing all permutations and combinations.

Answer (score 2):

`A a = new A();` 
Here a can access all data members and member functions of class A.
Whereas
`A b = new B();` here b can access only those member of class A which are present in class B.
This concept is called upcasting and it is done to achieve abstraction in java where we want child class method to be executed by parent class.

Answer (score 2):

Line 1: `A a = new A();`

the method existence will be checked in A class and the method will be called from A class also.

```
a.g();//A class method will be called
```

Line 2: `A b = new B();`

the method existence will be checked in A class and the method will be called from B class.

```
b.g();//B class method will be called and it will also check that it is available in A also or not if not then compile time error.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A a = new A();
```

You can access the members of A and at runtime method implementations in class `A` executes.

if you do `a.g()`, that calls the implementation in a Class `A`

```
A b = new B();
```

You can access the members of A and at runtime method implementations in class `B` executes.

if you do `a.g()`, that calls the implementation in a Class `B.

Inshort, that right side part decides which classes methods needs to execute.

I suggest you to read inheritance and polymorphism to understand deep.